# Cookie Law and Folcomedia - Cookies Alert

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, cookies

I'm using Joomla! 3.3.6 and Folcomedia - Cookies Alert plugin.

It's a great plugin but in Italy there is a very strict legislation, now.
Practically, the activation of third-party cookies (almost all!) is NOT permitted without agreement. So, I added some more changes, blocking ads and social modules if the cookie Folcomedia is not present, for example; and adding a page refresh when the navigator accepts, to load all missing modules.

This is already good but it's more than a week and I'm trying to integrate the agreement to scroll the page.
I'm not an expert but if I try with a php test page, it works, but it has no effect inside the plugin.

So, the first question, in my site are loading these jQuery, are they sufficient?

google.load("jquery", "1.6.1");

js/jquery.min.js
js/jquery-noconflict.js
js/jquery-migrate.min.js
js/jquery.cycle.all.js
js/jquery.simplemodal.js

If the cookie does not exist, the plugin loads this banner (at the bottom or the top of the page).

```
if ($type_affichage == 1) { $function_close = 'onclick="CloseCadreAlertCookie(); javascript:ssxl(\'LINK=Consenso%20Cookie\'); window.location.reload(true)"'; } 

        $text_btn_more = '<div class="'. $meme_ligne .' '.$span.' col-sm-6 btn_readmore" style="margin:5px 0;text-align:'.$position_btn_more.'"><a style="'.$couleur_btn_more_style.'color:'.$couleur_texte_btn_more.'" class="btn '.$couleur_btn_more.' '.$taille_btn_more.' read_more" href="'.JRoute::_("index.php?Itemid=".$link_readmore_menu).'#'.$ancre_link_readmore_menu.'">'.$texte_readmore.'</a></div>';
        $text_btn_more_poup = '<div class="'.$span.' col-sm-6 btn_readmore" style="margin:5px 0;text-align:'.$position_btn_more.'"><a style="'.$couleur_btn_more_style.'color:'.$couleur_texte_btn_more.'" class="btn '.$couleur_btn_more.' '.$taille_btn_more.' read_more" onclick="jQuery.magnificPopup.close();" href="'.JRoute::_("index.php?Itemid=".$link_readmore_menu).'#'.$ancre_link_readmore_menu.'">'.$texte_readmore.'</a></div>';
        $text_btn_close = '<div class="'.$meme_ligne.' '.$span.' col-sm-6 btn_close" style="margin:5px 0;text-align:'.$position_btn_close.'"><button '.$function_close.' style="'.$couleur_btn_close_style.'color:'.$couleur_texte_btn_close.'" class="btn '.$couleur_btn_close.' '.$taille_btn_close.' popup-modal-dismiss">'.$texte_close.'</button></div>';

        $text_out ='<div id="cadre_alert_cookies" style="opacity:'.$opacity.';text-align:'.$position_contenu.';'.$position_fixe_cookie.' margin:'.$marge_ext.'px;">';
        $text_out .='<div style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;margin:auto;max-width:'.$taille_cadre.';background-color: '.$fond_couleur.';'.$css_bordure.'">';
        $text_out .='<div style="display: inline-block;padding:'.$marge_int.'px;color: '.$texte_couleur.'"><div class="cadre_texte '.$meme_ligne.'">'.$texte.'</div>';
        $text_out .='<div class="cadre_bouton '.$meme_ligne.'">';
```

And this script in page:

```
if ($type_affichage == 1) {

            $script = '<script type="text/javascript">';
            $script .='var name = "fmalertcookies" + "=";';
            $script .='var ca = document.cookie.split(";");';               
            $script .='for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {';
            $script .='var c = ca[i];';
            $script .='while (c.charAt(0)==" ") c = c.substring(1);';       
            $script .='if (c.indexOf(name) == 0){ document.getElementById("cadre_alert_cookies").style.display="none";}';
            $script .='}';          
            $script .='var d = new Date();';
            $script .='d.setTime(d.getTime() + ('.$duree_cookie.'*(24*60*60*1000)));';
            $script .='var expires_cookie = "expires="+d.toUTCString();';
            $script .="function CloseCadreAlertCookie(){document.getElementById('cadre_alert_cookies').style.display='none'; document.cookie='fmalertcookies=true; '+expires_cookie+'; path=/'}";
            $script .="</script>";

            // Position Haut
            if ($position == 0) {
                $buffer = preg_replace('/<body(.*?)>/i', '<body$1>'.$text_out.$script, $buffer);
            }
            // Position Bas
            elseif ($position == 1) {

                $parts = explode('</body>', $buffer);   
                if (sizeof($parts)<2) {
                    return; // il n'y a pas </body> dans la page
                }

                $parts[sizeof($parts)-2] .= $text_out.$script;
                $buffer = implode('</body>', $parts);                           
            }
        }
```

Have you any suggestions to supplement the closing div and setting the cookie to scroll the page? Thank you.

I do not know if I have given all the necessary information ...

Answer (score 2):

You should not load jQuery from google for a simple reason. There is almost 90% chance it will be loaded from system (so better require it from system like this: `JHTML::_('jquery.framework')`) so you lose both bandwidth and performance. Not to mention possible conflicts. If script you made don't work on Joomla page there is already a huge chance you have conflicts/errors in Java Script. Use a debugger.